# Finding relationship between Laplace-Beltrami operators of two spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $S$ and $T$ be spheres with radius $R_S$ and $R_T$ respectively. Define the diffeomorphism $\Phi:S \to T$ by $\Phi(s) = \frac{R_T}{R_S}s$. Given a function $u:T \to \mathbb{R}$, we can define $\tilde u:S \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$\tilde u(s) = u(\Phi(s)) = u\left(\frac{R_T}{R_S}s\right).$$

**I am trying to write the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_T$ of $u$ in terms of $\Delta_S$ and $\tilde u$.** I start with the formula

$$\Delta_{S(R)} f(x) = R^2\Delta f\left(R\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\tag{1}$$
which holds for any sphere $S(R)$ of radius $R$.

Using this I see that
$$\Delta_S \tilde u(s) = R_S^2\Delta \tilde u\left(R_S\frac{s}{|s|}\right) = R_S^2\Delta u\left(R_T\frac{s}{|s|}\right)$$
with the last equality by definition of $\tilde u$. I want to say this is equal to $$\frac{R_S^2}{R_T^2}\Delta_T u(s)$$ by the formula (1). But then since $s \in S$ it doesn't make sense to write the above expression since we are taking the Laplace-Beltrami over $T$. And I'm not sure that I can use (1) because in (1) $x \in S(R)$, and here $s \in S$ and not $s \in T$.

How do I do this calculation correctly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the expression $\Delta_T\, u(s)$ doesn't make sense when $s \in S$.

To understand what to replace it with, notice the definition of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on spheres, which you quoted in formula (1).

The function $f$ on the left-hand side can be thought of as a function that's *only defined* on the sphere of radius $R$.

On the right side, we take the regular (Euclidean) Laplacian. This is *NOT* the Laplacian of $f$. It is the Laplacian of the spherical-extension of $f$, which is the function
$$x \mapsto f\left(R \frac x {\left|x\right|}\right)$$

This can be a bit confusing. When you write $\Delta f\left(R \frac x {\left|x\right|}\right)$, it might appear as if you're taking the regular Laplacian of $f$ and plugging in $R \frac x {\left|x\right|}$ (which is absurd, as $f$ is not even defined in any open set of the Euclidean plane, so it has no Euclidean Laplacian!). It might be more instructive (but more cumbersome) to write instead $\Delta\left(x \mapsto f\left(R \frac x {\left|x\right|}\right)\right)$, or to define an auxiliary function (the extension) of which the Laplacian will be taken.

Now, what properties does this extension of $f$ have?

1. It is defined on the entire Euclidean plane except $0$.
2. Its value doesn't depend on the *size* of the parameter, because the parameter is normalized. I.e. $x$ and $a x$ receive the same value for any $a > 0$. (This is a very important property)

---

Back to your problem: To simplify the calculations I'll introduce new notations to the extensions of $u$ and $\tilde u$ to the entire plane (minus the origin), and I'll call them $U$ and $\tilde U$:

$$U(x) = u\left(R_T \frac x {|x|}\right)$$
$$\tilde U(x) = \tilde u\left(R_S \frac x {|x|}\right)$$

But notice that $U$ and $\tilde U$ are actually exactly the same function! Follow their definitions (and the "equality" of $u$ and $\tilde u$) to see why this is true.

By definition of the Laplace-Beltrami operator, for any $s \in S$ and $t \in T$:

$$\Delta_T\, u(t) = R_T^2\, \Delta U(t)$$
$$\Delta_S\, \tilde u(s) = R_S^2\, \Delta U(s)$$

To proceed, we need to study the function $\Delta U$ and see how it behaves with respect to "stretching" the parameter. That is, given $\Delta U(x)$, what is $\Delta U(a x)$ for $a > 0$?

Notice that, by definition, $U(x) = U(ax)$ for $a > 0$. By differentiating both sides of this equation twice and using the chain rule, we get:

$$\frac {\partial^2} {\partial x_i^2} U(x) = a^2 \frac {\partial^2} {\partial x_i^2} U(ax)$$

Adding up all the partial second derivatives we get:

$$\Delta U(x) = a^2 \Delta U(ax)$$

for any $a > 0$.

Finally, using all of the above, we can make the calculation you wanted. Let $t \in T$ be some value and let $s \in S$ be defined by $s = \frac {R_S} {R_T} t$. Then:

$$\Delta_T\, u(t) = R_T^2\, \Delta U(t) = R_T^2\, \Delta U\left(\frac {R_T}{R_S} s\right) = R_S^2\, \Delta U(s) = \Delta_S\, \tilde u(s)$$

The conclusion: Thanks to the normalization in the definition you used of the Laplace-Beltrami operator (the multiplication by the radius squared), the value of the Laplacian does not depend on the radius of the sphere on which any given spherical function is defined.

Comment: Thank you! In your last sentence you wrote "..which any given spherical function is defined" -- by spherical function do you mean "function defined on the sphere"? Because $u$ is not necessiarly satisfying $u(x) = u(|x|)$.

Comment: I wrote the conclusion in a more informal language ad I used the word "function" a bit more loosely. Understand it like this: Define a **"function on any sphere"** as an equivalence class of functions on all origin-centered spheres (of different radii), that are all "equal" in the way that your $u$ and $\tilde u$ are equal. Then their Laplace-Beltrami operators are "equal" in the same sense.

Comment: Ah ok, so as long as I define the diffeomorphism $\Phi$ like I did it should be ok.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.

Comment: In the last displayed equation, when you substituted $s$, you converted a Laplacian wrt. the variable $t$ to a Laplacian wrt. the variable $s$. Is this a mistake?

Comment: No, this is the point. The Laplacian is with regard to the "parameter of $U$", not with regard to $t$ or $s$ (those values are just "plugged into" the Laplacian, i.e. $\Delta U(t)$ means $(\Delta U)(t)$). When I did this conversion I also "converted" from $U$ to $\tilde U$, but since $U = \tilde U$ (see in the middle of my answer), I just continued writing $U$.

Comment: Sorry, just got confused re-reading it!! thanks.

Comment: Can this be said starting from the local coordinate expression for the Laplace-Beltrami operators? I think that's essentially what I am asking in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559367/laplace-beltrami-operators-on-differently-scaled-spheres-are-they-the-same

Comment: @YoniRozenshein I am still confused about the last equation in the answer, I guess I do not really understand your reply to the comment where riem question transition between Laplacians w.r.t. $s$ and $t$. In particular, I do not understand why the following equality holds: $$ R_T^2\, \Delta U\left(\frac {R_T}{R_S} s\right) = R_S^2\, \Delta U\left(s\right).$$

Comment: If you agree that for any $a>0$ we have $\Delta U(x) = a^2 \Delta U(ax)$ (which is a conclusion we reached toward the end), then you should derive this equality with $a = \frac {R_T}{R_S}$.